# TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed to modify and excel file converted into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
data = pd.read_excel("Kitchen.xlsx")
dict_data={}
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
   if(data["Yes_No"][i]=="yes"):
       if(data["Menu"] in dict_data.keys()):
           dict_data[data["Menu"][i]].append(data["Specification"][i])
       else:
           dict_data[data["Menu"][i]]=list(data["Specification"][i])
menu=pd.read_csv("Menu.csv")
menu["Menu"]=""
for i in range(menu.shape[0]):
   name=menu["Name"][i]
   comb=list(FC["Combinations"][i].split("+"))
   l=[]
   for c in comb:
       l.append(dict_data[c])
   all_combinations=list(itertools.product(*l))
   for men_cmb in all_combinations:
       s=""
       for item in men_cmb:
           s+=str(item)+"||"
       menu["Menu"][i]=s
       i+=1
menu.to_csv("Menu.csv")
```

I want to print a combination of ingredients for a menu. This is my first time usong itertools so i dont really know what that error means. I basicly want to print all posible combinatios to do a menu with different ingredients. Menu.csv is my final excel but in Kitchen.xls i have the ingredients.

this is the output

```
C:\VEpython\Scripts\Drivers\Scripts>C:/Users/212803155/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/VEpython/Scripts/Drivers/Scripts/import pandas as pd.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/VEpython/Scripts/Drivers/Scripts/import pandas as pd.py", line 7, in <module>
    if(data["Menu"] in dict_data.keys()):
  File "C:\Users\212803155\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1798, in __hash__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

C:\VEpython\Scripts\Drivers\Scripts>
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to use itertools in such a verbose manner, can you post your input data (as inline code as above) as well as your expected output? You'll get a better reponse that way. Take some time to tour the site and read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is more fundamental and not related to itertools: mutable types are not hashable unless they provide a `hash` method!

This happens with simple types too, but the error is clearer.

```py
>>> set().add({'a':1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Hello ti7 :) so this problem should be resolved if i write the code you post? In what part should i write it? could you tell me how it works?